# How to translate Lisp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, lisp

I have some legacy code, which uses *Lisp* as it's scripting language. To broaden, ease and accelerate scripting I'd like to replace *Lisp* by *Javascript*.
In order to be able to built on all present scripting files, I first need to translate all `lsp` to `js`.

Now I found *parenscript* but am not yet sure what it is good for (seems to modify Javascript to be able to run lisp, which is not what I want).
Also there are some converters on the web, which seem to work quite well.
Has anyone already done this and can share some experiences, best pracises and tools?

Comment: If you're looking for a button that just converts it all, you're out of luck.  Language translation isn't something that can be automated.

Comment: @SomeKittens That's entirely untrue - compilers do *exactly* that all the time. Now, language translation while maintaining human readability, **there's** something that can't necessarily be automated.

Comment: @Tacroy I agree but in this case it may not be so hard. Lisp and JavaScript are structurally extremely similar.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I guess so, but seeing as how it's legacy Lisp I imagine there will be a great deal of hairiness in the JS version - legacy codebases tend to explore all of the weird and wonderful edge cases of a language, and those end up translating very poorly (e.g, Lisp macros). I definitely would prefer to maintain the Lisp version myself.

Comment: @Tacroy I don't have a problem if I have to fix 5% of the codebase as long as 95% of scripts are converted correctly. E.g. I know that I have to handle usage of dash in variable names

Comment: @LCIDFire, if macros are used the right way, you'll end up manually converting 95%, not 5%. And the resulting code will be really ugly.

Comment: @SK-logic, there is at least no `defmacro` in the code.

Comment: @LCIDFire, then it is not quite a Lisp code anyway. Feel free to translate it verbatim into JS. It should be trivial to write such a translator from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp is huge, and writing a compatible compiler / runtime is out of question for a novice. Parenscript is probably your best bet for direct running of your Lisp code on a JS target.

For simpler versions, like Scheme, there's a [ready-made interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/js-scheme/).

If you understand basic Lisp, take also at look a [Clojure](http://clojure.org/lisp), a Lisp variant. Chances are you might port significant chunks of Lisp code to Clojure without a major rewrite. Then apply their [JS compiler](http://clojure.org/clojurescript) and see if it works for you.

JavaScript has quite Lispy internals (despite the bolted-on OOP features), so efficient translation of moderate amounts of *simple* Lisp code (e.g. without macros) to JS is not impossible to do by hand.

The bottom line is: there's no silver bullet. You'd better learn some Lisp to handle your task. (Try it; it's well worth it, and also forever changes the way you see programming.)

Comment: Ahem, I do know Lisp, or I would not even try.